# How do I set redirectParams from a hook in FormIt, MODx revo?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, formit

How do I set `redirectParams` from a hook in FormIt, MODx revo? I need it in order to redirect the user to the view page after the edit with the correct ID of what was edited. The problem is: if ID wasn't known before the hook (as is the case when there's new stuff being created), I can't set `redirectParams` right, or can I?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I worked around this limitation by introducing a hidden input with name 'id', setting it to the correct ID in a hook, and then redirecting to a FormItRetriever page, where I retrieve ID and redirect yet again.

Answer (score 0):

`$hook->formit->setOption( 'redirectParams', json_encode( [ 'param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2' ] ) );`

Where `$hook` is the `\Sterc\FormIt\Hook` instance set by FormIt when running the hook snippet.